# Finding the set of values of the real number $a$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 1n - \sin \frac 1n)^a$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

> Find the set of values of the real number $a$ for which $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 1n - \sin \frac 1n)^a$ converges.

I had been stuck on this problem for a while but now I have managed to deduce following :

Using Maclaurin series for $\sin$ function,

$$\sin \frac 1n=\frac 1n - (\frac 1n)^3 \frac {1}{3!} + (\frac 1n)^5 \frac {1}{5!} - (\frac 1n)^7 \frac {1}{7!}+\dots$$
which implies
$$\frac 1n - \sin \frac 1n = (\frac 1n)^3 \frac {1}{3!} - (\frac 1n)^5 \frac {1}{5!} + (\frac 1n)^7 \frac {1}{7!}-\dots$$
and finally
$$0 \le (\frac 1n - \sin \frac 1n)^a \le ((\frac 1n)^3 \frac {1}{3!})^a$$
where the first inequality follows from the result : $\sin x \le x \; \forall x\gt 0$.
Hence
$$ 0 \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 1n - \sin \frac 1n)^a \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((\frac 1n)^3 \frac {1}{3!})^a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{3!})^a \frac 1{n^{3a}}=(\frac {1}{3!})^a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^{3a}}.$$

Last inequality converges for $3a \gt 1.$

Thus the given series converges for $a \in (\frac 13, \infty).$

Are there any loopholes in this solution? What are other ways to think about this problem?

Comment: This is how I would do it.

Comment: You did not prove that the series is not convergent for $a\leq 1/3$.

Comment: @RobertZ Ah I see.

Comment: Instead of the MacLaurin series, use the Taylor series to the first few terms, and then proceed by comparison. it'll be more direct than handling all the terms of the series by upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not prove that the series is not convergent for $a\leq 1/3$. Actually, by using a similar argument you can show that there are two positive constant $C_1$, $C_2$ and $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, 
$$\frac{C_2}{n^3}\leq \frac 1n - \sin \left(\frac 1n\right)\leq \frac{C_1}{n^3}$$
which implies that given series converges if and only if  $a>1/3$.

P.S. The existence of the above constants follows from the limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac 1n - \sin \left(\frac 1n\right)}{\frac {1}{n^3}}=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: can you pls tell me how did u quickly write this quickly. Given this i can prove by using $f^{'}(x) >0$. Also i know the expansion of $\sin x$ which contains alternatively postive and negative terms

Comment: @anirudhb See my P.S.

Comment: Great! I took time to understand this. $C_2 = \frac {1}{12}$ and $C_1= \frac {1}{3}.$ This is a standard approach.

Comment: @RobertZ how did u get that intuition? it's very cool. Is it a standard result or u got it by some intuition?

Comment: @anirudhb No, it's a standard result. If $(a_n)_n$ and  $(b_n)_n$ are positive sequences and $\lim_{n}a_n/b_n=L\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ then $\sum_n a_n$ converges iff $\sum_n b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

For the divergence:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^{a}&\geq\sum_{n}\left(\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{n^{3}}-\frac{1}{5!}\frac{1}{n^{5}}\right)^{a}\\
&=\frac{1}{(3!)^{a}}\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{3a}}\left(1-\frac{3!}{5!}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{a}\\
&\geq\frac{1}{(3!)^{a}}\frac{1}{2^{a}}\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n^{3a}}
\end{align*}
for large $N$, so it diverges for all $a\in(0,1/3]$. For $a\leq 0$ is clear, because the tail does not converge to zero.

Comment: It's a good observation that $1 - \frac {3!}{5!} \frac {1}{n^2} \ge \frac 12 \; \forall \; n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Yes, it is even true for all $n$ for $1/2$, but all I need is to have a strictly greater than zero as a lower bound, so for large $N$ will do.